# Sending data with websocket and authentication with jwt

Tags: javascript, express, websocket, jwt

General purpose:
I send the data from the client side to the server, the server sends the jwt to the client, and I send the same jwt to the server again to open it with the secretKey, and if so, I send true to the client.

I send the data to the server

```
    loginBtn.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
            e.preventDefault();

            let data = {
                mobile: mobile.value,
                password: password.value
            };
            console.log(`first send from client`);
            ws.send(JSON.stringify(data));
        });
```

I look for it on the receiving server and in the database, if it exists, I create a token and send it to the client

```
    wss.on('connection', (ws) => {
      let token;
      ws.on('message', (msg) => {
        let data = JSON.parse(msg);

        console.log(`give data from client in server : ${msg}`);
    
        database.query(`SELECT * FROM users WHERE mobile=?`, [data.mobile], (err, result) => {
          if (err) throw err;

          console.log(`this is result.length : ${result.length}`);
          if (result.length > 0) {
            const uuid = result[0].uuid;
            token = jwt.sign({
              mobile: data.mobile,
              uuid: uuid
            }, secretOrPrivateKey, {
              expiresIn: '7d'
            });
            console.log(`send token from server : ${token}`);
            ws.send(token);

          } else {
            ws.send('false');
          }
        });
      });
```

I receive the token in the client and send it again to the server for authentication

```
    ws.onmessage = (msg) => {
            let token = msg.data;
            localStorage.setItem('jwt', token);

            console.log(`second send from client(token) : ${token}`);
            
            // send token to server
            ws.send(token);
        };
```

And I receive it on the server and confirm it with the secret key, and if it is confirmed, I send true to the client, and if it is not confirmed, I send false.

```
  ws.on('message', (msg) => {
    console.log('this msg for JWT verification : ' + msg);
    let data;
    try {
      data = jwt.verify(msg, secretOrPrivateKey);
    } catch(err) {
      console.log(err);
      ws.send('false');
      console.log(`data is not create in server for JWT verification`);
      return;
    }
    if (data) {
      console.log(`data have value`);
      ws.send('true');
    } else {
      console.log(`data not have value`);
      ws.send('false');
    }
  });
});
```

If true is sent to the client, it will be redirected to the desired page with the user's uuid

```
        ws.onmessage = (msg) => {
            console.log(`give data from client ${msg}`);
            
            if (msg.data === 'false') {
                errorMsg.innerHTML = 'password incorrect!';
            } else if (msg.data === 'true') {
                try {
                let data = jwt_decode(token);
                location.href = `<%= "http://localhost:3000/messaging/${data.uuid}" %>`;
                } catch (err) {
                console.log(err);
                }
                
            }

        }
```

jwt_decode method :

```
function jwt_decode(token) {
            let base64Url = token.split('.')[1];
            let base64 = base64Url.replace(/-/g, '+').replace(/_/g, '/');
            let jsonPayload = decodeURIComponent(atob(base64).split('').map(function (c) {
                return '%' + ('00' + c.charCodeAt(0).toString(16)).slice(-2);
            }).join(''));

            return JSON.parse(jsonPayload);
        };
```

But it doesn't work and I get this in the server and browser:

server logs :

give data from client in server : {"mobile":"12345678956","password":"pass1234"}
this msg for JWT verification : {"mobile":"12345678956","password":"pass1234"}
JsonWebTokenError: jwt must be a string
at module.exports [as verify] (/home/arta/project/vsCode/farawin/chatApp/node_modules/jsonwebtoken/verify.js:64:17)
at WebSocket. (/home/arta/project/vsCode/farawin/chatApp/server.js:52:18)
at WebSocket.emit (node:events:525:35)
at Receiver.receiverOnMessage (/home/arta/project/vsCode/farawin/chatApp/node_modules/ws/lib/websocket.js:1184:20)
at Receiver.emit (node:events:513:28)
at Receiver.dataMessage (/home/arta/project/vsCode/farawin/chatApp/node_modules/ws/lib/receiver.js:541:14)
at Receiver.getData (/home/arta/project/vsCode/farawin/chatApp/node_modules/ws/lib/receiver.js:459:17)
at Receiver.startLoop (/home/arta/project/vsCode/farawin/chatApp/node_modules/ws/lib/receiver.js:158:22)
at Receiver._write (/home/arta/project/vsCode/farawin/chatApp/node_modules/ws/lib/receiver.js:84:10)
at writeOrBuffer (node:internal/streams/writable:392:12)
data is not create in server for JWT verification
this is result.length : 1
send token from server : eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJtb2JpbGUiOiIxMjM0NTY3ODk1NiIsInV1aWQiOiI2ZmZkNjZhMC01MmQwLTRhMGEtOWQ4Ni1iOGFiNzYwZDQ1YmEiLCJpYXQiOjE2ODM2NzMyMDYsImV4cCI6MTY4NDI3ODAwNn0.8iIKQOX3eAHAwE-P99jhzkvhMtvbjK9PDSgjQL1Qiv0

browser logs :

first send from client
give data from client [object MessageEvent]